# how to set desired selection in comboviewer programatically

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface

I want to set a value to the ComboViewer programatically. I'm trying to get the value from an object and set it by using setSelection(Iselection) in this way viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(Object) , but the value is not updated on the ComboViewer Selection. Could any one help me on how to set the selection of ComboViewer programatically?

Comment: @wastl   I've tried using setSelection(new StructuredSelection(Object)), in order to set my desired object to be set on the viewer. The object which I'm trying to set is available on the ComboViewer. Is this the right way I'm doing, please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 5):

I did that recently. You need to focus on if the values that are being set in the combo and the value you are setting match. Try printing them or stepping through.

This is what needs to be done -

```
// set up comboViewer
comboViewer = new ComboViewer(leftSectionComposite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
comboViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider()); // Use your label provider if possible.
comboViewer.setInput(YOURVALUES);

// set value

final ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(valueFromComboThatYouWantToSet);
comboViewer.setSelection(selection);
```

Comment: @ ND27 : I've stepped through, it is still not working. The value which i'm trying to set and value which is in the input list of viewer both are same, but still it doesn't work

Comment: Share your code.. your label providers and values you are setting

Comment: I've shared my answer, please verify it . Thanks

Comment: better to use ArrayContentProvider.getInstance() instead new ArrayContentProvider()

Answer (score 0):

```
// set up comboViewer
comboViewer = new ComboViewer(leftSectionComposite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider().getInstance());
comboViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if (element instanceof OwnerClass)

                              return ((OwnerClass)element).getName();
             return super.getText(element);
            }
        });); 

comboViewer.setInput(getService().getOwnerClass());


Person p = (Person)selection.getFirstElement();
final ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(p.getOwnerClassObj().getName());

comboViewer.setSelection(selection);
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the selection to the _name_ of owner class, but the objects in the comboviewer are owner classes themselves, not strings.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeah, but in the label providers iam sending them as names

Comment: So you always want the first element to be displayed? 
is this the correct code - as it shouldn't compile as you are using selection before defining it.

Comment: @suj No, you are _showing_ them as names. The actual content is the objects returned by content provider, and that's what you should pass to selection.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I even tried passing in the actual object list, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ND27 Hi, here the first element is im selecting from the table viewer and the property of that must be displayed in the comboviewer which ever i select on the tableviewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum CarType {
    SUV, MPV, Hatchback, Sedan;
}

// ...
cv = new ComboViewer(aComposite);
cv.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
cv.setInput(CarType.values());

//THE BELOW LINE HAVE WHAT YOU WANT
final ISelection defaultValue = new StructuredSelection(CarType.Sedan);
cv.setSelection(defaultValue);
```